# IntelliJ - why does the terminal has different environment variables values

Tags: java, intellij-idea, environment-variables, java-8

I have recently replaced Java 7 to Java 8.
All regular apps in IntelliJ runs smoothly.
All but the tomcat apps - which run from the cmd command line but not from IntelliJ.

It fails to load due to an error in the JRE_HOME definition.
I have oviously defined JRE_HOME in the env variables and in the jdk settings.
I have executed

```
echo %jre_home%
```

both in the IntelliJ terminal and in the cmd and received different values
(IntelliJ terminal showed unupdated value.).
Where are the variables in the terminal declared?
How do I change them?

Answer (score 13):

I don't know about old IntelliJ versions, but in 2019.2.3 one can configure environment variables in project settings. Be aware, you need to restart existing terminal or create new terminal tab to see the effect.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you saved me some time.

Comment: This was super handy for using an alternative ssh key with git. Now all my terminals have the right setting and I don't need to even think about it

Answer (score 12):

If you are launching IntelliJ via the JetBrains ToolBox **it will cache the `$PATH` variable** so recent changes will not appear.

Just **close and re-open JetBrains Toolbox**.

Answer (score 8):

Almost 5 years later, I have the same issue on Windows 10 and had to restart my computer to solve it.

Edit:
The best solution is to not define a JRE_HOME environment variable. I don’t know why but IntelliJ stucks using that env variable.

Comment: Same for me. I can confirm that on Windows 10 I had to restart the machine. Restarting IntelliJ IDEA had no effect ...

Comment: when a java/jre is installed seperately through oracle installer etc.it is setting the JRE_HOME/jre into the PATH.

Answer (score 4):

For me it was because IntelliJ IDEA did not launch the shell as a "login" shell. All of my environment variables are set as I expect in a login shell, but in a non-login shell, many of them are missing.

By way of example, I expect `/usr/local/bin` to be in my PATH, but that is only true within login shells (as I get when I run iTerm2). This is an excerpt from a terminal session within IntelliJ IDEA:

```
amacleod@valjean ~> echo $PATH | grep -c /usr/local/bin
0
(1) amacleod@valjean ~> $SHELL --login
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
amacleod@valjean ~> echo $PATH | grep -c /usr/local/bin
1
```

One possible workaround would be to add my expected PATH and other variables to the shell configuration for non-login shells, but I would really rather just always be in a login shell.

I would have hoped that IntelliJ IDEA would have a checkbox for sending `--login` in the Terminal settings. However, it is possible to override the *Shell path* setting to include the login flag.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me, invalidating the system cache or restarting IntelliJ didn't reload the updated environment variables.

After restarting the computer, it enabled IntelliJ to pick up the updated environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

1. Close all IntellJ windows and any process that may currently be using the wrong SDK.
2. Navigate to the folder where your JDK is installed (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java`).
3. Rename the wrong SDK so something else (e.g. `jdk-11.0.5.OLD`). If it won't do this, you may still have a process running using that SDK; go back to 1.
4. Start IntelliJ again.

Answer (score 1):

Invalidating the systems cache should do the trick. see [JetBrains: Invalidate Cache](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html).

Any other measures (like closing projects and IDE seemed to work only on a per project basis and only after a while (when IDE detected that the cache is invalid by itself ...)

---

Edit:
Correction - Unfortunately, after having the corrected the environment in all terminals *for a while*, IntelliJ "*reverted*" to the old, incorrect environment in any of my projects. Now I hope that after a reboot - as posted by akuman8 - the issue is solved. (If not, I will stick to a commandshell of my choice ***outside*** the IDE, where everything works fine ...)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIKT, the intellij terminal on linux is just the same as running a standalone terminal session. It's just conveniently located in the IDE.

In response to the question, "How do I change [the terminal environment variables]?"

I'm using virtualenvwrapper to manage my terminal's environment variables for different environments, such as dev, test and production. It's working just as well for java development as it was for python development.

https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org

Answer (score -2):

It seems you can define project specific environment variables:

> In IntelliJ project specific environment variables you can set under
>   Run/Debug configurations --> Defaults --> Application --> Environment
>   variables

from:
http://emmanuelbernard.com/blog/2012/05/09/setting-global-variables-intellij/#comment-617922540
[image]

Comment: Thanks. But where is the old JRE_Home is taking from? 
I want to erase it's reference.

Comment: As far as I know, IJ uses the default shell of the OS (for windows cmd.exe, you can specify which executable to use though.
Therefore the env variables should be the same as when you execute cmd.exe (or applicable executable on other platforms) yourself

Comment: thanks. definitely not the case at my env. btw, it is in tomcat debug configuration. not application.

Comment: It was just to illustrate where the control was. You have to choose your own run/debug config of course.
What do you mean by "erase it's reference"?

Comment: @mish You're mixing this up. These variables are for specific configurations for quickly launching your application / running tasks / etc. They are not reflective of what is displayed in the terminal.

Comment: Tried this solution in Intellij 15.05 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It did not change environment variables for the intellij terminal on my system. My solution: I'm using virtualenvwrapper to manage my terminal's environment variables for different environments. Working just as well for java as it is for python development. https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org

Comment: Good luck doing that when you have to run tests - you will have to set variables manually each time you run a different test.